# Why is my spatial join returning different results using the sp versus the sf package?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp, r-sf

In the following reprex, I run a spatial join on some point and polygon data, but unexpectedly get different results when using the `sp` package from when I use the `sf` package. Why is this?

I am trying to count `acled` points within `prio` grid squares, but as shown below, my counts differ between packages even though running a `st_covers` join from `sf`, should to my knowledge be functionally the same as using the `over` method from `sp`.

```
library(sp) # packageVersion("sp") #> [1] ‘1.2.7’
library(sf) # packageVersion("sf") #> [1] ‘0.6.3’
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(dplyr); library(tibble)
```

Here is the sample data I'm working with:

```
# prio (polygon squares) and acled (points); in both sp and sf objects:

# prio sf polygons object
priosf <- structure(list(
  CELL_ID = c(180365, 176783, 150830, 145866, 140055), 
  gwno = c(615L, 616L, 432L, 626L, 475L), 
  POP = c(111983.7, 107369.7, 12169.35, 23005.76, 527012.1), 
  prio_country = c("Algeria", "Tunisia", "Mali", "South Sudan", "Nigeria"), 
  geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(2, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 35, 35.5, 35.5, 35, 35), 
                                                     .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
                            structure(list(structure(c(11, 11, 11.5, 11.5, 11, 32.5, 33, 33, 32.5, 32.5), 
                                                     .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
                            structure(list(structure(c(-5.5, -5.5, -5, -5, -5.5, 14.5, 15, 15, 14.5, 14.5), 
                                                     .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
                            structure(list(structure(c(32.5, 32.5, 33, 33, 32.5, 11, 11.5, 11.5, 11, 11),
                                                     .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
                            structure(list(structure(c(7, 7, 7.5, 7.5, 7, 7, 7.5, 7.5, 7, 7), 
                                                     .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), 
                       class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, 
                       bbox = structure(c(-5.5, 7, 33, 35.5), 
                                        .Names = c("xmin", "ymin", "xmax", "ymax"), 
                                        class = "bbox"), 
                       crs = structure(list(epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), 
                                       .Names = c("epsg", "proj4string"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), 
              .Names = c("CELL_ID", "gwno", "POP", "prio_country", "geometry"),
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), 
                                          class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), 
                                          .Names = c("CELL_ID", "gwno", "POP", "prio_country")))

# prio sp polygons object
priosp <- as(priosf, 'Spatial')

# acled data
acled <- structure(list(
  EVENT_ID_CNTY = c("ALG3195", "ALG3316", "ALG4228", 
      "ALG4824", "MLI1050", "MLI1144", "MLI1423", "MLI1672", "NIG4606", 
      "NIG4951", "NIG6196", "NIG7661", "NIG9100", "SSD1216", "SSD1504", 
      "SSD3232", "SSD3234", "SSD3231", "SSD3239", "TUN1376", "TUN2597", 
      "TUN3217", "TUN3633"), 
  COUNTRY = c("Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", 
              "Algeria", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
              "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "South Sudan", "South Sudan", 
              "South Sudan", "South Sudan", "South Sudan", "South Sudan", "Tunisia", 
              "Tunisia", "Tunisia", "Tunisia"), 
  LATITUDE = c(35.2122, 35.4343, 35.2122, 35.2122, 14.8252, 14.8252, 14.7414, 14.8252, 7.3028, 
               7.3028, 7.3028, 7.3028, 7.3588, 11.05, 11.05, 11.05, 11.05, 11.05, 11.05, 32.8487, 32.7149, 32.7149, 32.7149), 
  LONGITUDE = c(2.3189, 2.2166, 2.3189, 2.3189, -5.2547, -5.2547, -5.3282, -5.2547, 7.0382, 7.0382, 7.0382, 7.0382, 7.0994, 32.7, 32.7, 32.7, 32.7, 32.7, 32.7, 11.4309, 11.012, 11.012, 11.012)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -23L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  .Names = c("EVENT_ID_CNTY", "COUNTRY", "LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE"))

# acled sf points object
acledsf <- st_as_sf(
  acled,
  coords = c('LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'),
  crs = 4326
)

# acled sp points object
coordinates(acled) <- ~LONGITUDE+LATITUDE
  proj4string(acled) <- proj4string(priosp)
acledsp <- acled; rm(acled)
```

`sp` package spatial join result. I bound the polygons that intersect with every point, joined the result to the points, and then counted the number of CELL_IDs (polygons):

```
# sp spatial join:
addPolyDataToPts <- function (points, poly) {
  polysByPoint <- over(points, poly)
  points <- spCbind(points, polysByPoint)
}

acj <- addPolyDataToPts(acledsp, priosp)

(acled_count_sp <- acj@data %>% filter(!is.na(CELL_ID)) %>%
  group_by(CELL_ID, prio_country, POP) %>%
  summarize(acled_sp = n()) %>% arrange(CELL_ID) %>%
  rename(prio_country_sp = prio_country))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   CELL_ID, prio_country_sp [5]
#>   CELL_ID prio_country_sp     POP acled_sp
#>     <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>    <int>
#> 1 140055. Nigeria         527012.        5
#> 2 145866. South Sudan      23006.        6
#> 3 150830. Mali             12169.        4
#> 4 176783. Tunisia         107370.        4
#> 5 180365. Algeria         111984.        4
```

Analogous `sf` package spatial join result, where my count column `acled_sf` is different from the above `acled_sp` column for all but one polygon square. (140055; Nigeria):

```
# sf spatial join:
(acled_count_sf <- 
  st_join(priosf, acledsf, join = st_covers) %>%
  group_by(CELL_ID, POP, prio_country) %>%
  summarize(acled_sf = n()) %>% ungroup %>% 
  arrange(CELL_ID) %>%
  rename(prio_country_sf = prio_country))
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_covers assumes that they are planar
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 4 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -5.5 ymin: 7 xmax: 33 ymax: 35.5
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   CELL_ID     POP prio_country_sf acled_sf                        geometry
#>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>              <int>                   <POLYGON [°]>
#> 1 140055. 527012. Nigeria                5 ((7 7, 7 7.5, 7.5 7.5, 7.5 7, …
#> 2 145866.  23006. South Sudan            4 ((32.5 11, 32.5 11.5, 33 11.5,…
#> 3 150830.  12169. Mali                   1 ((-5.5 14.5, -5.5 15, -5 15, -…
#> 4 176783. 107370. Tunisia                6 ((11 32.5, 11 33, 11.5 33, 11.…
#> 5 180365. 111984. Algeria                1 ((2 35, 2 35.5, 2.5 35.5, 2.5 …
```

My running theory is that one method is binding values in an incorrect order but I'm not sure which. In my larger sample, I get similar values but bound to different polygons i.e. '2706' points get matched to Cell 1 for the `sf` join and to Cell 2 for the `sp` join.

(And, in some cases some values are outright missing from the `sf` join)

Any insight into how or why my results differ in this way would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it took me plotting the data in mapview to figure out what was going on here, but at least in your given reprex, your issue is caused because you specified your longitude and latitude backwards when you created the `acledsf` object. Created in the correct order and the join outputs match:

```r
# acled sf points object
acledsf <- st_as_sf(
  acled,
  coords = c('LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE'),  ###notice the correct order here
  crs = 4326
) 

# acled sp points object
coordinates(acled) <- c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE")
proj4string(acled) <- proj4string(priosp)
acledsp <- acled; rm(acled)


addPolyDataToPts <- function (points, poly) {
  polysByPoint <- over(points, poly)
  points <- spCbind(points, polysByPoint)
}

acj <- addPolyDataToPts(acledsp, priosp)

(acled_count_sp <- acj@data %>% filter(!is.na(CELL_ID)) %>%
    group_by(CELL_ID, prio_country, POP) %>%
    summarize(acled_sp = n()) %>% arrange(CELL_ID) %>%
    rename(prio_country_sp = prio_country))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   CELL_ID, prio_country_sp [5]
#>   CELL_ID prio_country_sp     POP acled_sp
#>     <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>    <int>
#> 1  140055 Nigeria         527012.        5
#> 2  145866 South Sudan      23006.        6
#> 3  150830 Mali             12169.        4
#> 4  176783 Tunisia         107370.        4
#> 5  180365 Algeria         111984.        4


### sf
(acled_count_sf <- 
    st_join(priosf, acledsf, join = st_covers) %>%
    group_by(CELL_ID, prio_country,  POP) %>%
    summarize(acled_sf = n()) %>% ungroup %>% 
    arrange(CELL_ID) %>%
    rename(prio_country_sf = prio_country))
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_covers assumes that they are planar
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 4 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -5.5 ymin: 7 xmax: 33 ymax: 35.5
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   CELL_ID prio_country_sf     POP acled_sf                        geometry
#>     <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>    <int>                   <POLYGON [°]>
#> 1  140055 Nigeria         527012.        5 ((7 7, 7 7.5, 7.5 7.5, 7.5 7, …
#> 2  145866 South Sudan      23006.        6 ((32.5 11, 32.5 11.5, 33 11.5,…
#> 3  150830 Mali             12169.        4 ((-5.5 14.5, -5.5 15, -5 15, -…
#> 4  176783 Tunisia         107370.        4 ((11 32.5, 11 33, 11.5 33, 11.…
#> 5  180365 Algeria         111984.        4 ((2 35, 2 35.5, 2.5 35.5, 2.5 …
```

Comment: Thanks dpseidel, is `mapview` a package I should be aware of?

Comment: Yes definitely! It's great for doing quick visual checks and inspecting spatial data. It's interactive so you can easily tell which points are not where you expect them to be. https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/